# What does the colon in µ-η2:η2-O2 mean?

Tags: notation

In the formula $\ce{[nBu4N]2[(UO2)2(\mu-\eta^2:\eta^2-O2)(NO3)2(\mu-Au(CN)2)2]}$, what does the colon stand for? Is this an official notation?

Comment: Can we have a source?

Comment: $\mu$ means that the $\ce{O2}$ ligand is bridging two metal centres, i.e. it is bound to two different metal atoms/ions. $\eta^2$ means that the $\ce{O2}$ ligand is acting as a bidentate ligand (i.e. both oxygens are bonded to the metal). $\eta^2\text{:}\eta^2$ means that the $\ce{O2}$ ligand is acting as a bidentate ligand towards *both* metal centres.

Comment: So, it looks something like this (the structure of oxyhemocyanin, bottom): http://web.tock.com/kalee/chem32/spec/Image1.gif There, $\ce{O2}$ (in the middle) is acting as a bidentate ligand towards two copper centres. In your compound I presume it is acting as a bidentate ligand towards two U centres. Now, as to whether it is an "official" notation, IR-2.5.2, IR-10.2.3.1, and IR-10.2.5.1 (notably the text accompanying Example 21 on p 222) in the 2005 Red Book mention this use of colons.

Comment: Source: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36064040#36064040

Comment: In the [Red Book](https://www.iupac.org/fileadmin/user_upload/databases/Red_Book_2005.pdf) p. 28 defines "Colons are used in *names* in the following ways." (italics as in the original). Page 222 (examples 21 to 25) has more examples. But these are all for compound *names*, not formulae. Is it allowed or common to mix both notations?

Comment: Good catch. I looked through again and can't find any examples of the use of the colon in a name. However, as far as I can tell it is permissible to use both μ and η in formulae, see IR-4.6.5 (p 67) and Table V (p 259). The colon is not a structural descriptor such as μ and η; it simply serves to delineate two structural descriptors. Just based on this, I would assume that the use of : in formulae is allowed, but I acknowledge it isn't really hard proof.

Answer (score 5):

This notation is mentioned in the IUPAC Nomenclature of Inorganic chemistry, Recommendations 2005 (‘[Red Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_Red_Book)’):

> **IR-10.2.5.1** *The eta (η) convention*
>
> The special nature of the bonding of unsaturated hydrocarbons to metals *via* their π-electrons
>   has led to the development of the ‘hapto’ nomenclature to designate unambiguously the
>   unique bonding modes of the compounds so formed. (…) The Greek
>   symbol η (eta) provides a topological description by indicating the connectivity between the
>   ligand and the central atom. The number of contiguous atoms in the ligand coordinated to the
>   metal is indicated by a right superscript numeral, e.g. η<sup>3</sup> (‘eta three’ or ‘trihapto’), η<sup>4</sup> (‘eta
>   four’ or ‘tetrahapto’), η<sup>5</sup> (‘eta five’ or ‘pentahapto’), *etc*.
>
> (…)
>
> If an unsaturated hydrocarbon serves as a bridging ligand, the prefix μ (see Sections
>   IR-10.2.3.1 and IR-10.2.3.4) is combined with both η and κ, where necessary. The colon is
>   used to separate the locants of the bridging ligand which indicate binding to different metal atoms.
>
> (…)
>
> Examples:
>
> 21.
>
> [image]
>
> (μ-η<sup>2</sup>:η<sup>2</sup>-but-2-yne)bis[(η<sup>5</sup>-cyclopentadienyl)nickel](Ni—Ni)

(This convention is not used for unsaturated hydrocarbons only, there is also a more complicated example (25) with carbonyl (CO) ligand.)

Use of this notation for *formulae* does not seem to be explicitly mentioned or “allowed”. If it is not an omission in the rules, I think that such construct could be called a name-formula hybrid, which might useful for detailed description the discussed structure detail in a shortest way possible.

The $\ce{[^{n}Bu4N]2[(UO2)2(\mu-\eta^2:\eta^2-O2)(NO3)2(\mu-Au(CN)2)2]}$ polymeric complex is described in [1], which talks about $\ce{U-O2-U}$ linkage with bidentate peroxo ($\ce{O2^{2-}}$) unit.

References:

1. Brown, M. L.; Ovens, J. S.; Leznoff, D. B. [Dicyanoaurate-Based Heterobimetallic Uranyl Coordination Polymers](https://doi.org/10.1039/C7DT00942A). *Dalton Transactions* 2017, 46 (22), 7169–7180.